# Minimum and maximum version of Maven compatible with Java 17

Tags: java, maven, java-17

As of the title, I am searching the range of Maven versions that ensures compatibility with Java 17, but I can't find anything on web or in Maven documentation.

Comment: Maven has only a minimum required JDK version (8) for Maven 3.9.X (https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) Maven will run up to JDK 21 ...https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk21 / https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/06/2023-06-24-how-to-use-jdk21-preview-features-incubator/

Comment: I don't think this is answerable ... since compatibility is also going to depend on the versions of the maven plugins that you could possibly be using.

Comment: All of the most recent plugin versions (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) working... also can be checked via https://ci-maven.apache.org/job/Maven/job/maven-box/job/maven-dist-tool/job/master/site/dist-tool-prerequisites.html

Comment: Maybe the author of the post can explain what is meant by compatibility and what kind of problems you have?

Comment: What is the underlying reason you need to know this?

Comment: There is usually no reason to use a Maven version before 3.8.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question cannot be answered clearly. The reason is, that [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) is organized in [plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html). And the plugins are responsible for executing the corresponding tools of the JDK and other tasks. For example:

- [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html): executes `javac` (or more specifically uses `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` by default).
- [`maven-jar-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/): assembles the `.jar` (it does that autonomously without using the `jar` command).
- etc.

It is also a common (and good) practice to have the plugin versions explicitly defined in the `pom.xml`.

Since Java has been quite gentle regarding backwards compatibility of artifacts so far (that strategy seems to [shift a bit](https://openjdk.org/jeps/451) for the sake of security) it is able to execute Maven releases from ages ago. So there are uncountable options of version combinations (actually the root cause is that Java lacks of shipping it's own proper build tool and does not have a default repo like `nodejs` has with `npm` - a gap that Maven and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) are filling up).

At the same time Maven is very gentle regarding upwards compatibility of its plugins as long as the same model version is used (which has been version 3 for a long time now) and other dependencies are compatible, most importantly [Plexus](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/).

For example you can run Maven and compile Java 17 sources using the [oldest Maven 3 version available](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.0/) - which is **3.0**, dating back to 2010. Even a `modules-info.java` is compiled correctly, because Java is responsible for it - not Maven. However this version has configured central repositories [using `http` instead of `https`](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/release-notes.html#switch-access-to-maven-central-to-https-mng-5672), which is rejected by the servers by now, but you could change that configuration of course.

Supported features is another thing. For example the [`--release`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-D343F6B4-3FDD-43A8-AD24-43DD70214471) option added to `javac` with Java 9 is supported by `maven-compiler-plugin` from 3.6.x and newer (specified through `maven.compiler.release`). However even with Maven 3.0 you can use `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.10.1, which has been released 12 years later (it stops working with 3.11.0, though).

Lets take another feature example: Java 9 Modules. There are still some Maven plugins, that do not fully support it, like the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). It can modify regular classes, but [not a `modules-info.class`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-234).

Finally let me rephrase your questions to

> What is the oldest Maven version usable out of the box without configuration changes?*

**3.2.3**

> Is it compatible with Java 17?

Basically, yes

> Is it recommended to be used?

Definitely, no

> What is the recommended version?

The latest, **3.9.5***

> Do **all** Maven plugins around have a version fully compatible with the latest Java version?

No. There will never be.

* as the time of writing

Comment: PS: The default plugin versions per release can be found under a page with the bulky name "Plugin Bindings for default Lifecycle": https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html

Comment: There is one misconception in this answer. Mixing the support of particular features (the mentioned one not related)  and building with JDK21 or other versions..Also I wrote the most recent versions... Some words about maven-shade-plugin and JPMS could not work and will not because the maven-shade-plugin will break the idea of JPMS (intentionally it does so)... so it does not make sense...The usage of https instead of http for central is based on security and is not related to JDK version... (https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https) nor with Maven itself...

Comment: A very clear answer for a question that can't be answered clearly ;)